# How to pass an array to an OracleParameter for IN condition?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Here is the way I try to execute an sql command:

```
List<int> idsToDelete = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };

string sqlDel = @"DELETE FROM products WHERE product_id IN (:idsToDelete)";

using (OracleCommand cmdDel = new OracleCommand(sqlDel, connexion))
{
    cmdDel.Parameters.Add("idsToDelete", idsToDelete.ToArray());
    cmdDel.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

I get the following exception:

> Unable to cast an object form type 'System.Int32[]' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

I get the same exception with the following command:

```
string sqlDel = @"DELETE FROM products WHERE product_id IN :idsToDelete";
```

I ther a proper way to set a mutli value parameter for an IN condition?
I don't want to format the command string, because it has to be reusable.

Comment: Do you want the resulting SQL to be "... IN (1,2,3)"?

Comment: `string sqlDel = $@"DELETE FROM products WHERE product_id IN ({string.Join(", ", idsToDelete)})";` or you have to create a parameter for each item in `idsToDelete`

Answer (score 1):

Don't know whether this is best practice, but it should work:

```
List<int> idsToDelete = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };

string sqlDel = @"DELETE FROM products WHERE product_id IN (";
sqlDel += string.Join(", ", idsToDelete);
sqlDel += ")";

using (OracleCommand cmdDel = new OracleCommand(sqlDel, connexion))
{
    cmdDel.Parameters.Add("idsToDelete", idsToDelete.ToArray());
    cmdDel.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Let me know if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can either join items into `IN`

```
List<int> idsToDelete = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };

string sqlDel = 
  $@"DELETE 
       FROM products 
      WHERE product_id IN ({string.Join(", ", idsToDelete)})";

using (OracleCommand cmdDel = new OracleCommand(sqlDel, connexion))
{
    cmdDel.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Or create parameter for *each* item within `idsToDelete`:

```
string sqlDel = 
  $@"DELETE 
       FROM products 
      WHERE product_id IN ({string.Join(", ", Enumerable.Range(0, idsToDelete).Select(i => $":prm_Del{i}"))})";

using (OracleCommand cmdDel = new OracleCommand(sqlDel, connexion))
{
    for (int i = 0; i < idsToDelete.Count; ++i) {
      //TODO: A better choice is explict parameter creation:
      //   cmdDel.Parameters.Add($":prm_Del{i}", idsToDelete[i], OracleType);  
      cmdDel.Parameters.AddWithValue($":prm_Del{i}", idsToDelete[i]);
    }

    cmdDel.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try  <kbd>[String.Join()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8)</kbd>

```
cmdDel.Parameters.Add("idsToDelete", string.Join(",", idsToDelete));
```